# "Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" when importing a function through a barrel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import

I have a function in a file called merge, which contains inside it

```
export default (prev, next) => Object.assign({}, prev, next)
```

I also have a [barrel](https://dev.to/luispa/how-to-create-barrels-in-typescript-or-javascript-59ma) which imports and exports this function like

```
import fetchToNode from './fetchToNode'
import mergeObjects from './mergeObjects'

export {
    fetchToNode,
    mergeObjects
}
```

If I import the function from it's origin (`import merge from 'src/functions/merge'`) everything works fine.

If I try to import this function from the barrel however (`import {merge} from 'src/functions'`) then I get the error

`redux.js:449 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

Comment: Do you have index.js file in functions folder?

Comment: @DipenShah yes.

Comment: Could you share codesandbox? I not sure if you are exporting correctly.

Comment: @DipenShah What's in the question is exactly what I have for exports

Answer (score 1):

You are not exporting from the barrel correctly. Try something like this:

`src/functions/index.js:`

```
export { default as mergeObjects } from './mergeObjects';
export { default as fetchToNode } from './fetchToNode';
```

and then

```
import { mergeObjects, fetchToNode } from 'src/functions';
```

The way you've exported it is for the following usage:

```
import functions from 'src/functions';

console.log(functions.merge) // merge function
```

You can check out this [useful link about barrel exports](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel)

See how it curates these examples for the barrel?

```
export * from './mergeObjects'; // re-export all of its exports
export * from './fetchToNode'; // re-export all of its exports
```

In our case, we don't need to re-export all of the exports (but the snippet above also works), but only the `default` of it, since your function is written as such:

```
export default (prev, next) => Object.assign({}, prev, next)
```

Thus `export { default as merge } from './merge'`  **default** means on `export default () ...` from the function above in `merge.js`

Comment: The above is how I've always written my barrels, and I don't understand the {default as merge } from './merge'

Comment: @Sam Are you saying this is the code which is not working? Since I can see in your question that you've used a different type of barrel export

Comment: I will add additional info to the answer

Comment: How do I write this when I'm exporting multiple functions from the barrel

Comment: Multiple functions as in, `merge.js`, `foo.js`, `bar.js` ? Each different function in its own file?

Comment: I added an edit to show my whole barrel. I figured it out, but don't understand why this is the fix. What is the difference between your barrel method, and my barrel method. Why is my method different, it seems to work whenever I use it on React components

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222428/discussion-between-antonio-erdeljac-and-sam).

Comment: I feel like one comment would suffice, and would be useful if anyone else ends up on this question

Comment: StackOverflow recommended it to me, thought it would be easier :) The difference is that you are trying to export an object literal, meaning that you are handling exports as normal objects, which is a no-go for ES6 imports / exports flow. Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: So in my barrel I'm exporting a literal object, which contains the functions `fetchToNode` and `mergeObjects`. I think I always do exports like this and it works fine. Why would this situation cause a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was a solution, but it turns out that it doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Update your barrel file to and it should fix it:

```
export * from './fetchToNode'
export * from './mergeObjects'
```